# Проблема с списком кнопок PyQt5: все кнопки ссылаются на одну программу вместо разных

Tags: python, gui, pyqt5

Есть кусок кода, который должен создать массив Pushbutton объектов. Все хорошо, картинки погружаются, кнопки рисуется. Проблема в том, что все кнопки ссылаются на одну программу вместо разных. Вот код:

```
        for i in range(0, len(self.btn_name)):
        if i<=4:
            temp = QPushButton("", self)
            temp.resize(170, 170)
            temp.setStyleSheet(
                "background-image:url({}) no-repeat;background-size: 30px 40px;".format(self.btn_image[i]))
            temp.move(20+200*i, 30)
            temp.clicked.connect(lambda: call(["{}".format(self.btn_path[i])]))
            print(self.btn_path[i])
            self.buttons.append(temp)
```

Кусок кода:

```
print(self.btn_path[i])
```

дает:

```
C:/Program Files (x86)/Google/Chrome/Application/chrome.exe
C:/Program Files (x86)/JetBrains/PyCharm Community Edition 2016.3.2/bin/pycharm64.exe
C:/Program Files/Android/Android Studio/bin/studio64.exe
C:/Program Files/Git/git-bash.exe
```

Поясните, что сделать, что б нормально работало.

Comment: связанный вопрос: [Why results of map() and list comprehension are different?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/139819/4279)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Когда `lambda` из `temp.clicked.connect()` вызывается, то используется текущее (последнее значение) `i`. Чтобы исправить:

```
temp.clicked.connect(lambda i=i: call(["{}".format(self.btn_path[i])]))
```

[Why do lambdas defined in a loop with different values all return the same result?](https://docs.python.org/3/faq/programming.html#why-do-lambdas-defined-in-a-loop-with-different-values-all-return-the-same-result)

Comment: все одно не работает, Все кнопки теперь идут к самой первой програме со списка

Comment: @Oleg_Hudyma: мой ответ исправляет *один* баг в вашем коде. Это не значит, что у вас других багов нет. Создайте минимальный, но полный пример кода, который вашу проблему демонстрирует и обновите вопрос. [mcve]