# Необычное поведение области видимости: изменяемый аргумент по умолчанию

Tags: python, область-видимости

Столкнулся с одной особенностью Python'а не могу найти материал по этой теме, подскажите почему так происходит

```
def foo(lst = []):
    lst.append(1)

    return lst

foo()
foo()
lst = foo()

print(lst)
```

Вывод

```
[1, 1, 1]
```

Comment: А что тут не так?

Comment: lst = [] не стирается при новом вызове

Comment: Похожий вопрос: ["Least Astonishment" and the Mutable Default Argument](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1132941/4279)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Инициализация аргументов по-умолчанию происходит 1 раз - до вызова функции.

`lst = []` - тут создается список, который используется для всех последующих вызовов функции, т.е. вызывая функцию без аргумента, вы всегда работаете с одним и тем же объектом.

```
l = foo()
k = foo()
id(l) == id(k) # True
l is k # True
```

Comment: `id(l) == id(k)` - отличная идея !

Comment: @MaxU `a is b` сравнение само по себе уже необходимо и достаточно, чтобы определить один объект или нет (`id()` функция, если не предопределена, идентичный  оператору is результат, для объектов, которые одновременно существуют, должна возвращать: `id(a) == id(b)` равнозначно в этом случае `a is b`). Если результат id() ещё как-то не используется, то `a is b` более предпочтительно (читаемо, всегда одно и тоже обозначает).

Answer (score 5):

Из-за того, что в Python аргументы с значением по умолчанию вычисляются единожды в момент объявления функции, для [примера с изменяемыми объектами](http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/writing/gotchas/) (например, контейнерами типа `list`, `dict`, `set`, и т.п.) нужно так оформлять:

```
def foo(lst=None):
    if lst is None:
        lst = []

    lst.append(1)
    return lst

foo()
foo()
lst = foo()
print(lst)  # [1]

my_list = [0]
lst = foo(my_list)
print(lst)  # [0, 1]
```

---

Такая особенность не коснется неизменяемых объектов (типа чисел, строк и т.п.), так что смело можно их использовать:

```
def foo(lst=None, value=1):
    if lst is None:
        lst = []

    lst.append(value)
    return lst
```

Comment: +1 за пример, который намерение автора реализует (создать новый список, если он не был передан). В сторону: используйте `[]`, если у вас нет специальных оснований в частном случае вызвать `list()`.

Comment: @jfs, предпочитаю [] -> list, {} -> dict/set, () -> tuple из-за внешней схожести скобок :)

Comment: я не верю, что вы настолько часто `[]` и `()` путаете (они постоянно в программах встречаются в роли `__getitem__`, `__call__`). Это конечно не строгое требование, но в публичном коде, если в конкретном случае  (для читателей вашего кода) нет особых обстоятельств, то лучше явные константы использовать `[]` вместо `list()`. В тему вопрос: [`[]` and `{}` vs `list()` and `dict()`, which is better?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5790860/4279)
 (там производительность обсуждается, но я считаю главное это читаемость кода и `[]` является более идиоматичным способом).

Comment: `>>> l = [lambda x: x * y for y in range(10)]
>>> l[0](10)
90
>>> l[5](10)
90`
Что тогда можно сказать про это?

Comment: @shotInLeg, заменить на `l = [lambda x, y=y: x * y for y in range(10)]`

Comment: @jfs, в начале изучения питона перепутал, потом долго разбирался почему код не работает как должен быть, после заметил опечатку и решил, что пустые контейнеры через встроенные функции буду создавать, инициализированные -- через литералы. Наверное, имеет смысл пересмотреть мнение и после приводить к одному виду -- литеральному, а встроенные функции, типа list, использовать для конвертации :)

Comment: @shotInLeg [похожая проблема](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/644468/23044)

Answer (score 4):

в Python аргументы по умолчанию вычисляются единожды в момент объявления функции,а не при вызове функции( как например это сделано в руби)